# Как вывести всю строку с определенным словом?

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть например строка
name='man'
age='24'
как мне найти строку в котором содержится слово name и вывести её вместе с содержимым

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = '''
привет меня
зову Михаил
а, как зовут тебя?
'''

word = input()

for i in text.split('\n'):
    if word in i:
        print(i)
        break
```

Если хочешь, чтобы выводились все строчки со словом, убери break.

Answer (score 0):

```
found = 'name=\'man\' age=\'24\'' # Строка
founs = input() # Имя переменной
for i in found.split(' '):
    if founs in i:
        result = i[i.index('\'') + 1:-1] # Результат
```

Comment: Не совсем так мне нужно найти слово в большом текстовом файле и вывести всю строку с ним и вопрос как найти и как вывести